# Expressing Ramanujan $\tau$ function as Cauchy product of divisor function

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am trying exercises from Apostol Modular functions and Dirichlet series in number theory and I am stuck on this problem from Chapter -1 .

Problem image is 
[image]

Image of theorem 1.18 
[image]

I am not able to think how to prove this result

Can someone please help.

Comment: You find $k$ such that $E_4^3-E_6^2=k\Delta$, and compare the coefficients of $q^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Your definitions are equivalent to the following versions given by Ramanujan :
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\tau(n)q^n&=q\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-q^n)^{24}=\eta^{24}(q)\notag\\
Q(q)&=1+240\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^3q^n}{1-q^n}=1+240\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sigma_{3}(n)q^n\notag\\
R(q) &=1-504\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^5q^n}{1-q^n}=1-504\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sigma_{5}(n)q^n\notag
\end{align}
It can be proved with some effort that $$Q^{3}(q)-R^{2}(q)=1728\eta^{24}(q)$$ and from this it follows that $$1728\tau(n)=240^3((\sigma_{3}\circ\sigma_{3})\circ\sigma_{3})(n)-504^2(\sigma_{5}\circ\sigma_{5})(n)$$ and dividing by $1728$ we are done.

Comment: The name is $\Delta,E_4,E_6$, the effort is to show they are weight $12,4,6$ modular forms (from the Fourier expansion of $\sum_{n,m}(n+mz)^{-k}$) so that $\frac{E_4^3-E_6^2}{\Delta}$ is a weight $0$ modular form thus it is constant $\frac{E_4^3-E_6^2}{ \Delta}= c, c=3 .240+2 .504$

Comment: @reuns: one can show the identity algebraically by using the differential equations satisfied by $P, Q, R$ (ie $E_2,E_4,E_6$) $$q\frac{dP} {dq} =\frac{P^2-Q}{12},q\frac{dQ}{dq}=\frac{PQ-R}{3},q\frac{dR}{dq}=\frac{PR-Q^2}{2}$$ and from that one concludes that $$q\frac{d} {dq} (Q^3-R^2)=P(Q^3-R^2)$$

Comment: @reuns: the effort in establishing the differential equations in my approach is non-trivial and can be compared to establishing that the functions involved are modular forms of appropriate weights.

Comment: Those differential equations follow from the modularity too

Comment: @reuns : Perhaps you might have noticed from my activity here that "complex analysis" and "abstract algebra" are my weaknesses so I prefer the Ramanujan Jacobi approach based on usual algebra and calculus.

Comment: The [$\theta\to \eta$ identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Relations_to_Dedekind_eta_function)  also follow from the modularity (constructing a weight 12 cusp form to relate to $\eta^{24}$) thus so does the Jacobi triple product, in other words knowing how to prove the modularity of $f$ when it is modular is very useful